# Web service method returns Response object instead of custom object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have the following code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("_webServiceAuth")]
    public User GetUser(string username)
    {
        try
        {
            this._validationMethods.Validate(_webServiceAuth);
            User user = new User(username);

            return user;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, one would expect to receive a User as a responce when I do:

```
myUser = this.Service.GetUser(username);
```

But what I get is a request for a "GetUserRequest" instance, and get returned a "GetUserResponse" instance. Any help in why my object is not being send by my webservice?

Comment: You should remove that try/catch block. It does nothing except screw up your stack when an exception is thrown. it will look like the exception came from the "throw" statement.

Comment: True that, it's exactly what's doing and I find myself lost every time that happens!. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find that the GetUserRequest object has a string property (username), and the GetUserResponse object contains your User object.  These Request/Response objects are containers that exist in the SOAP messages.

I believe they are normally abstracted away but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see my User object inside the GetUserResponse. Update: Forget that last comment, found it xD